# executing insert\update\deletes - Use Linq?

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, linq-to-sql

I was looking at using linq to sql (or EF) rather than in line\dynamic sql within my application but have hit a possible issue. My application modifies data against any number of random databases accross several sql instances, linq appears to structured towards a single database scenario. Would it be best to just continue using in line sql or is there a method of using linq without tying it down to a single database?

An example of what I'm doing at the moment:

```
Using cn As SqlConnection = (ConnectionString)
        Using cm As SqlCommand = New SqlCommand("< Dynamic sql>;", cn)
            cn.Open()
            cn.ChangeDatabase(Database)
            cm.ExecuteNonQuery()
        End Using
 End Using
```

And example of a query would be:

```
DELETE FROM settings WHERE [Sec] = 'ON' AND [Key] = 'last'; INSERT Settings([Sec], [Key], [Val]) values('ON', 'last', GETDATE());
```

Although I am executing stored procedures within these databases, some custom, others for adding users (sp_adduser)

All target databases have the same structure, so any query\linq would work against it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With LINQ, you are correct in that a DataContext goes to one single database, but you can have many DataContexts, each going to a different database. You can have, for example, a SettingsDataContext going to the database with your settings and a UsersDataContext going to the database with your users, or however you have it set up.

There is the syntax of it all. Here is a link to some examples of doing inserts and selects with ADO.NET and Linq to SQL.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/wriju/archive/2008/07/14/linq-to-sql-vs-ado-net-a-comparison.aspx

One thing I have heard often is that Linq to SQL is for those that aren't real comfortable with SQL or who just like to work in the realms of C# or VB.NET code more than having to switch thought patterns and think in the ADO.NET/inline SQL realm.

Comment: Hi Seeker - The target databases are restored daily by multiple people, not just static. (These databases are worked on for several hours before being removed). Would I have to create a DataContext per database on the fly?

Comment: So long as the database structures stay the same and the connection strings for the databases stay the same, it should work. And by structures, I mean table names, columns on the tables, data types of the columns, and stored procedure names, along with some things I'm sure I'm forgetting. Restoring the database shouldn't be a problem.